# Using Datagrid HeaderTemplate button to change Datagrid Row buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid bound to a collection of timesheet lines.

In each row I have included a custom usercontrol consisting of 3 Radio buttons in the last column. These indicate whether each line should be "Bill", "Hold" or "Write off".
In the header template for the datagrid, i have included a slightly different control which allows the user to select "Bill All", "Hold All", "Write Off All"

[The buttons in question...[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyqXe.png)

How can i get the header buttons to affect change on the row buttons beneath.

This is my first attempt at using WPF, and I'm trying to ensure i stick with proper WPF ideals and structures. I have tried to assign an Click event to the header buttons which would create an array of the row buttons, setting their IsSelected property to true.

But i'm sure i should be using something like an Attached Property.

These are the Radio buttons wrapped up into a UserControl

LineButtons.xaml

```xml
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsHitTestVisible="True">
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource GridLineButton}" x:Name="BillButton"  Template="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonLeft}">Bill</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource GridLineButton}" x:Name="HoldButton" Template="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonMid}">Hold</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource GridLineButton}" x:Name="WOButton" Template="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonRight}">Write Off</RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
```

HeaderButtons.xaml

```xml
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsHitTestVisible="True">
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource GridLineButton}"  >Bill All</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource GridLineButton}"  >Hold All</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource GridLineButton}"  >Write Off All</RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
```

Datagrid.xaml

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:HeaderButtons Padding="0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:LineButtons Padding="4"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I want all the row buttons to be setable from the header buttons.
E.g. If a user clicks Bill All (in the header) i'd like all the row "Bill" buttons to be set to Selected.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: OK, so i think i'm going about this all wrong. I'm going to post another question which i will link here.

Comment: I have now added a new quesion which focuses on binding to a property
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187558/how-do-i-make-the-ui-show-changes-to-a-collection-in-a-viewmodel